# Multiple cpu producers with few gpus not utilize 100% of the gpus (pytorch)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I tried to implement board game self-play data generation in parallel using multiple cpus to do self-paly concurrently. For parent process, i created 4 NN model for 30cpus (1 model for 10 cpus and 1 model to train) each model is in different gpus.(the model is implemented as 20 blocks resnet-like architecture with batchnorm) Pseudo code as follows

```
nnet = NN(gpu_num=0)
nnet1 = NN(gpu_num=1)
nnet2 = NN(gpu_num=2)
nnet3 = NN(gpu_num=3)

for i in range(num_iteration):
    nnet1.load_state_dict(nnet.state_dict())
    nnet2.load_state_dict(nnet.state_dict())
    nnet3.load_state_dict(nnet.state_dict())
    samples = parallel_self_play()
    nnet.train(samples)
```

parallel_self_play() is implemented as follows

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_cpu) #30
for i in range(self.args.numEps):
    results = []
    if i % 3 == 0:
        net = self.nnet1
    elif i % 3 == 1:
        net = self.nnet2
    else:
        net = self.nnet3

     results.append(pool.apply_async(AsyncSelfPlay, args=(net))
     # get results from results array then return it
     return results
```

My code work perfectly fine with almost 100% gpu utilization throughout the first self-play (less than 10 minutes for an iteration) but after the first iteration (training) when i loaded new weights into nnet1-3 gpu utilization never reach 80% again (~30min - 1hour per iteration). I notice a few things while mess around with me code

1. This model includes batchnorm layers, when switch model to train() mode -> train -> switch back to eval() causes the self-play (use forward pass from model) to not use gpu at all.
2. If it doesn't switch from eval() -> train() (train using eval mode) this causes gpu utilization to be lower  (30-50%) but not entirely gone.
3. If the models that are not the main one doesn't load the weights from the main one, self-play still utilize 100% gpu so my guess is that something happened during training process and change some states in the model.

This also happen when use only 8 cpus - 1gpu architecture and train model on the fly (no intermediate one).

Can someone guide me where to fix my code or how i should train my model?